# How to move a TPanel controlled by mouse at runtime?

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, firemonkey

I want to move a `TPanel` on another `TPanel` by mouse at runtime with Delphi 10.4.2 and FMX. I tried `OnMouseDown`, `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseUp` events. But it is not clear what the contents of `X` and `Y` values are in the events. The documentation says that they are screen coordinates. Relative to the screen, form, parent control or the control itself? How can I solve the movement of the `TPanel`?

Answer (score 0):

> The documentation says that they are screen coordinates.

No, it doesn't.  The [FMX.Types.TMouseEvent](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TMouseEvent) and [FMX.Types.TMouseMoveEvent](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TMouseMoveEvent)
documentation both say:

> X and Y--the pixel coordinates of the mouse pointer **within the client area of the control**.

> How can I solve the movement of the TPanel?

Like this:

```
var
  LastPt: TPointF;
  Dragging: Boolean = False;

procedure TMyForm.PanelToDragMouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft then
  begin
    LastPt := TPointF.Create(X, Y);
    Dragging := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.PanelToDragMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft then
    Dragging := False;
end;

procedure TMyForm.PanelToDragMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  CurrPt: TPointF;
begin
  if Dragging then
  begin
    CurrPt := TPointF.Create(X, Y);
    PanelToDrag.Position.Point := PanelToDrag.Position.Point + (CurrPt - LastPt);
    LastPt := CurrPt;
  end;
end;
```

Basically, while the mouse is moving around the Panel, the code is simply calculating the offset the mouse has moved from the last known position to the current position, and then applying that offset to the Panel's current `Position` within its `Parent`.

Comment: I changed my program. Now the Panel is moving. But not as exspected. The mouse moves faster than the Panel. So the mouse gets out of the Panel. When I move the mouse back to the Panel the Panel moves without pressing the left mouse button. Did you test this with FMX?

Comment: @PeterKloß "*Did you test this with FMX?*" - no, but this is typically the approach used in VCL, I just adapted it to FMX.

Comment: Panel1 HitTest=false; Regardless of whether Panel2 has Panel1 or Form1 as a parent, the error persists. The movement of Panel2 and Mouse are not synchronous. Panel2 jumps when moving and does not walk smoothly. I replaced TPointF.Create(X, Y) with Screen.MousePos(). Now everything works as expected. However, it doesn't work with ScaledLayout. Why? Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @PeterKloß It shouldn't matter whether `Screen.MousePos` or `X/Y` are used.  The goal of the code is to determine the amount of movement (delta) from one event to the next.  Either value should be able to accomplish that.  Are you suggesting that `(CurrPt - LastPt)` is not calculating the correct delta when `X/Y` are used?

Comment: The error occurs when using X,Y as described. A trace shows that the values are incorrect. Only with `Screen.MousePos` is it correct. Please try it yourself with FMX and Windows platform.

Comment: @PeterKloß "*the [X/Y] values are incorrect*" - in what way? That sounds like a bug in FMX then. "*Please try it yourself*" - I can't, actually. I don't have the IDE installed right now. It got lost in a system crash awhile back, and I haven't reinstalled it yet. But I have RTL/VCL/FMX source I can refer to.

Comment: The X/Y coordinates do not correspond to the actual mouse movements. Hence the wrong behavior. Without Delphi FMX System you can't understand that. TLabel in combination with TPanel also shows incorrect behavior. Should I create a new case for this?